# how to split long psql command in bash script over several lines

Tags: shell-script, postgresql

I have a long psql command to execute within a bash shell script, and I am wondering what the correct way is to split it across several lines?  The standard Unix script 'split line' backslash character doesn't work.  Within the postgres environment of course you could keep going line after line and the command doesn't get processed until you enter the closing semi-colon, but you don't use that within a shell script.

My command is this:

```
sudo -u postgres /opt/puppet/bin/psql puppetdb -t -c "select certname, r.value as role, e.value as env from certname_facts r join certname_facts e using (certname) where r.name = 'role' and e.name = 'env' order by role,env,certname" | grep -v "^$" > /home/ansible/inventory_list
```

I don't want to change the command, it all works perfectly when entered manually, but I need to know the correct way to make this into a split-line entry, something like:

```
sudo -u postgres /opt/puppet/bin/psql puppetdb -t
-c "select certname, r.value as role, e.value as env
from certname_facts r join certname_faces e using (certname)
where r.name = 'role' and e.name = 'env'
order by role,env,certname" | grep -v "^$" > /home/ansible/inventory_list
```

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: `.... -t\\n....env\\n...,.name)\\n....env'\\n....` where `\n` are literal newlines

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing wrong with splitting it up with backlashes as you showed. However, it's generally better to send the SQL via stdin. For postgres, this is especially true, since the '-c' option is fixed to return output from only one command, whereas accepting commands from stdin, you can stack as many commands together as you like. So, you would do something like:

```
sudo -u postgres /opt/puppet/bin/psql puppetdb -t  <<SQL | ...
  select certname, r.value as role, e.value as env
      from certname_facts r join certname_faces e using (certname)
      where r.name = 'role' and e.name = 'env'
      order by role,env,certname
SQL
```

Bash variables might get interpolated here. To avoid that, quote the first instance of `SQL`:

```
sudo -u postgres /opt/puppet/bin/psql puppetdb -t <<'SQL' | ...
```

Comment: Oh that's very neat, thank you, I think I'd rather do it that way.  May I just ask though, what purpose do the three elipses fulfill, that is, what is their script meaning?

Comment: Sorry, the ellipses are _representative_ of the rest of your pipeline, ie, your `egrep`.

Comment: For anyone who wants to learn more about that syntax: This is called a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells).

Comment: Why does the pipe (and rest of the pipeline) go inside the string?

Comment: The | follows your command. the "here" document starts immediately on the next line of the pipeline. So, the pipeline isnt going 'inside the string' (This makes it impossible to have a multiline statement AND a heredoc simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I just tried using the standard backslash character and it worked, so:

```
sudo -u postgres /opt/puppet/bin/psql puppetdb -t \
-c "select certname, r.value as role, e.value as env \
from certname_facts r join certname_faces e using (certname) \
where r.name = 'role' and e.name = 'env' \
order by role,env,certname" | grep -v "^$" > /home/ansible/inventory_list
```

I had been told by a DBA colleague that this would not work, since it's an sql command and not a 'standard' Unix command.  Seems I should have tried it for myself before believing!!

Comment: It's just a plain old double-quoted string, which is treated as such by the shell. Nothing magical about it just because it contains SQL!

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is type out your basic query, where you're doing something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name ...
```

And then you have more things -- like WHERE and ORDER BY; stuff like that -- and all you want to know is how to just fold this neatly on separate lines so you're not just typing out one continuous line of query, etc.

Just press enter when you want to go to the next line. Psql will not take the query until you put in your `;` .

Remember it is CASE SENSITIVE but not white-space sensitive as below example:

```
mycomputer=# SELECT *
mycomputer-# FROM sacramento 
mycomputer-# WHERE beds <= 1
mycomputer-# LIMIT 20;
```

It's also important to know that if you type in nonsense, psql will tell you nothing! It will just go to the next line.

Also good to know, that if you're writing out a longer query you know you'll use again, it is far more efficient to edit a file with the query, and call on it in psql with `\i file_name`.

The following blog post helped me a lot while getting started:

[postgresql-on-the-command-line](https://phili.pe/posts/postgresql-on-the-command-line)